# Java byte array - How can I manipulate the next n bits?

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I am working on algorithm that manipulates bytes, but not necessarily a value that is divisible by 8. The code puts a number in the first 32 bits that represents the length of a code. It then iterates through a collection which contains sets of numbers and characters. The number is put in the next n bits, represented by the code_length, and the char is put in the following 16 bits. How can I go about manipulating the bits?

```
byte[] result = new byte[numbits/8];
result[0]  = (byte) (code_length >> 24);
result[1] = (byte) (code_length >> 16);
result[2] = (byte) (code_length>> 8);
result[3] = (byte) (code_length);

while(iterator.hasNext())
{
   String next = iterator.next(); // The string is {code}:{char}, i.e. 4:c
   String values = next.split(":");
   int code = Interger.parseInt(values[0]);

   //Put code in the next code_length bits of result

   //Put values[1] in the next 16 bits of result

}
```

Comment: standard `&`, `|` and `^` bit masking? Googling for bit masking will find you loads of results, like http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

Comment: Maybe use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)?